# expect inside bash + open(slave pty): bad file number + parent: sync byte write: broken pipe

Tags: bash, expect

I am using expect script inside bash script. 
I tried to copy a file from remote host to local. The error I face is,

> open(slave pty): bad file number + parent: sync byte write: broken pipe

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter username: " username
read -s -p "Enter password: " password

#Expect script
/bin/expect -<<EOD 

set SERVERS {100 101 102}

foreach SERVER \$SERVERS {
set timeout -1
spawn scp ${username}@plsa\${SERVER}.corp.com:/log.2011-11-24 log.2011-11-24 
expect "*password:"; send "$password\r"
expect eof }
EOD
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but why are you wrapping the expect script with bash?  If the only thing you're doing in bash is reading a couple of lines of input, you might as well just move that into expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

send_user "Enter username: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n" {set username $expect_out(1,string)}

send_user "Enter password: "
stty -echo
expect_user -re "(.*)\n" {set password $expect_out(1,string)}
stty echo

set SERVERS {100 101 102}

foreach SERVER \$SERVERS {
set timeout -1
spawn scp ${username}@plsa\${SERVER}.corp.com:/log.2011-11-24 log.2011-11-24 
expect "*assword:"; send "$password\r"
expect eof }
```

You've now removed a whole layer of complexity, which might make the actual error easier to debug.  Also, note that scp prompts "Password", not "password", so you need to modify your match string as I've done here.

An additional question: can you use ssh key-based authentication for these connections instead of password authentication?  This would simplify the entire process -- you wouldn't need to muck about with expect at all in this case.  You could just do:

```
for server in 100 101 102; do
  scp -i mykey ${username}@plsa${SERVER}.corp.com:/log.2011-11-24 log.2011-11-24
done
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q68

> This is one of these "should not happen" errors. For example, the following question in this FAQ mentions that it could be the fault of the C library. Another possibility is that you've run out of some system resource (file descriptors). The most likely reason is that you're calling spawn in a loop and have neglected to call close and wait.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is old that re-opening old posts is considered bad fu, but a search for this error message keeps sending Google here, so I think this probably a good place to actually answer it.

In my experience, I found that one of the many possible causes for this has to do with the fact that Expect is making library calls to other programs on the system and, in my case, I was unable to run those secondary programs with my user permissions.  I have been unable to find out which library call is causing the issue, but a

```
username All=(ALL) /path/to/your/script
```

entered into `visudo` fixed it for me.  Obviously, you don't have to issue blanket permissions, but allowing the user to execute the script with sudo root permissions gave Expect the access it needed.  Just thought I would add this with the hope that it would help someone else in the future.